# Let $X \sim \mathrm{Multinomial} (n, p)$. What is the distribution of $X/n$?

Tags: distributions, multinomial-distribution

Let $n, k \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $p_1, \ldots, p_k \ge 0$ and $p_1 + \cdots + p_k = 1$. Let $p := (p_1,  \ldots, p_k)$ and $X \sim \mathrm{Multinomial} (n, p)$. This means $X$ follows a multinomial distribution consisting of $n$ independent trials in which the probability of outcome $i$ is $p_i$.

Then $\frac{X}{n}$ is a vector of probabilities. I would like to ask if the distribution of $\frac{X}{n}$ is already investigated and has some simple form.

Comment: Define $Y = X/n$,  Then $nY$ has a Multinomial($n,p$) distribution... this may help you find the solution.  As a note: $X/n$ isn't a vector of probabilities, it's a vector of observed frequencies.

Comment: Answered for the Poisson distribution at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240720/what-is-the-probability-mass-function-of-the-scaled-poisson-distribution/315177#315177.  The answer here will be essentially the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pmf of $\mathbf{X}$ is

$$P(\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x}) = n! \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{x_i}}{x_i!}$$

From this you can deduce that the pmf of $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}/n$ is

$$P(\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{y}) = P(\mathbf{X} = n\mathbf{y})   = n! \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{(ny_i)}}{(ny_i)!}$$